# remove from cart using form in template not working in Django

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-sessions

I'm building an Ecommerce App using Django, I'm storing my cart object in Django Sessions, Add to cart, reduce quanity & increase quantity seem to work perfectly on the products page but the same logic isnt working on the cart page. Django isnt throwing any errors. Below is the snippet of code of my form located inside a table on the Cart page & the view function handling its post request:
FORM:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="border rounded p-4 m-4">
         <p class="display-4 pl-4 ml-4">Your Cart</p>
         <hr>
         <table class="table">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Sno.</th>
                     <th>Image</th>
                     <th>Product</th>
                     <th>Price</th>
                     <th>Quantity</th>
                     <th>Total</th>
                     <th>     </th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 
                 {% for product in products %}
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                     <td>___</td>
                     <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                     <td>{{product.price}}</td>
                     <td>{{product|cart_quantity:request.session.cart}}</td>
                     <td>{{product|price_total:request.session.cart}}</td>
                     <td>
                       <form action="/cart/#{{product.id}}" method="POST">
                       {% csrf_token %}
                       <input hidden type="text" name="product" value="{{product.id}}">
                       <input hidden type="text" name="remove" value="True">
                       <input type="submit" value=" * " class="btn btn-block btn-light border-right">
                       </form>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
 
                 {% endfor %}
                
             </tbody>
 
             <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                     <th colspan="4"></th>
                     <th class="" colspan="">Total</th>
                     <th>{{products|total_cart_price:request.session.cart}}</th>
                 </tr>
             </tfoot>
         </table>
```

VIEW FUNCTION:

```
class Cart(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ids = list(request.session.get('cart').keys())
        products = Product.get_products_by_id(ids)
        return render(request , 'cart.html' , {'products' : products} )        

    def post(self, request):
        product = request.POST.get('product')
        remove = request.POST.get('remove')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        if remove:
            cart.pop(product)
        else:
            pass      

        return redirect('cart')
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently django sessions object needs to be made aware anytime any changes are to be made to the object inside sessions. The fix is to add :

```
request.session.modified = True
```

I'm testing this rn and it seems to work fine, what i dont get is why on the homepage it works without adding the modified command. If anyone has any further knowledge on this issue. Do share

Comment: The session doesn't store objects. It stores the serialized object. When you access it is turned back to a dictionary for your use but it is just stored as a string basically. Hence if you change the object the session would likely not know.